# Where are href's hidden in gmail "standard view" when parsing the HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a script in javascript that runs on the gmail.com inbox page, but I can only get it to work in gmail's "basic html view." I would like to understand how gmail makes the different emails in your inbox clickable and navigate to an href in "standard view" if there is no `<a>` tag with href when you inspect the element.

In summary, how is gmail's "basic html view" different from "standard view" and how do I find the href's associated with clickable inbox elements in "standard view" since I cannot just parse through `<a>` tags?

I think that the answer to this question will be crucial to my understanding more complex web coding and I appreciate any direction, links, etc. I haven't been able to figure this out with my own research.

Comment: It's likely all controlled through their JavaScript framework for the app. It's probably not simple.